# Alphabetise pre-populated select field

Tags: ee2, fieldtype, sort

I have a channel where each entry has a field called "Brand". This coincides with an entry title in a different "brands" channel. The best way I've found to set this up is to use a select field type and use the populate feature to draw in these titles. That all works perfectly with one problem...

How do I get it to populate the field in alphabetical order? Currently it's in order of entry which isn't alphabetic and so it's making it hard to use.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a select field type and pulling from another channel, you might try using a Relationships field. You can choose the field to order by and sort order as well. Then on your templates it also opens up more opportunity to more easily pull in additional info from other fields in your brands channel entries if needed.

Comment: Agreed. This will keep you from having to update your select field if you add a new Brand entry. I haven't used the new Relationships field yet, so I don't know if there's an option to sort alphabetically on the publish form, but [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa) definitely has that option.

Comment: The problem is I've got over 1,000 entries that would need updating and I'm making an educated guess that the relationship fields are stored as IDs and not titles. To be honest I'm not sure why I didn't use a relationship field for start, I'm sure there was a reason but I can't remember for the life of me what it was.

Is there perhaps a hook or something for sorting data in select fields? Thanks for the help so far.